# Force grub to accept windows installation

Tags: linux, grub, bios

I installed in my laptop some time ago a oracle linux server to make some test for my job., ok now i want to remove it and install windows from CD., but when i restart the pc he try to run the CD from inside, but GRUB passes over and run again the oracle linux server., so how can i force it to accept the uninstall? thanks

Answer (score 5):

GRUB can't pass over the CD drive; this is something setup in BIOS.  Either your Windows installation media isn't bootable for some reason or the laptop BIOS is set to try booting from the hard drive before the CD drive.

When your laptop is first turned on a message will appear, something like "Press XXX to enter Setup", where XXX is some key sequence.  Use that key to enter BIOS setup and change the boot order so that the CD drive is tried first.  If that doesn't make your laptop boot from the Windows CD, then the CD (or perhaps the CD drive itself) is defective.

Comment: thank you for your answer., i'm gonna try it tomorrow and i return with a answer about this uncommon issue .. btw why my question have downvote!?!